# Is it ok to exit a while loop like this when using input overload

Tags: c++, overloading, inputstream

re updated my question and found this fix to exit a while loop when using an overloading input stream, is this ok to use?? i don't want to use it just because it works.

```
int main()
{
    cout << "start" << endl;

    Vector<WindLogType> windlog;

    fstream file("MetData.csv");

    while (!file.eof())
    {
        WindLogType temp;

        file >> temp;

        windlog.insert(temp);

        if (file.peek() != EOF) {
            break;
        }
    }

    }

    cout << "end" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Note that you pass the `WindLogType` object to your input operator by *value*.

Comment: And unless it's part of your exercise or assignment, don't use your own `Vector` types, use the standard `std::vector`.

Comment: yeah its meant to be this way, dynamic array, its in the question.

Comment: Lastly, you don't need `typedef struct` in C++, all structure and class names are type-names.

Answer (score 0):

Use `break;` when you "hit" the exit-criteria